# Why isn't the CSS applying for Html.DropDownList in MVC?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

CSS is not applying for html.dropdownlist.please tell me how to apply CSS. Many dropitems are loading in my dropdown. To reduce the size I am applying the below css.

```
 <span id="filterByApplication"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByApplicationName", new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedApplication.Name), "ALL", new { @class = "drop-menu" })%></span>
```

CSS :

```
.drop-menu 
   {
    max-height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f6f0e4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .drop-menu li
  {
      position:relative;
  }
```

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure that the CSS matches the HTML? Does the `Html.DropDownList` create a list? I thought it created a `select` control...

Comment: Can you give us the rendered HTML? Are you sure that your select has the `.drop-menu` class?

Comment: <span id="filterByApplication"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByApplicationName", new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedApplication.Name), "ALL", new { @class = "drop-menu" })%></span> i wrote drop-menu class applying the style  like the above.

Comment: No no, the outputted HTML.